# Cambiar el background con isMouseOver en wpf?

Tags: wpf, style

Tengo un boton normal y le quiero hacer un cambio de color al background cuando el mouse esta encima, pero este no funciona del todo bien, cuando yo cambio el color a otro que no sea por defecto de mi boton, este no hace ningun cambio y se queda igual pero si yo le dejo el color por defecto si funciona, queria saber si se hacer algo al respecto

```
<Style x:Key="bt-Exit" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Este es el estilo de que quiero usar para mis botones y cuando le aplico un background a mi boton con el siguiente codigo:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Width="25" Height="25" Style="{DynamicResource bt-Exit}" Margin="762,2,11,2" Background="#FF7B1616"/>
```

El cambio de color con Trigger no hace el cambio de color pero si yo quito la propiedad background o la dejo por defecto este cambio si se aplica, hay alguna forma de resolver este problema?

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17259993/579895). El problema debe ser que los botones por defecto ya tienen un comportamiento asociado al mouse over, con lo que debes modificar el template del control

Comment: La manera más segura de obtener respuestas es revisando en inglés, muchas veces en otros foros, ya tienen la solución. Mira aquí la tuya: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf